# Master Page doesn't recognize a variable from a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have the following pages:

User Control

```
...
public partial class IDowner : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string owner;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      //do stuff           
    }
```

Master Page

```
<body runat="server">
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
<uc3:IDowner id="IDuser1" runat="server" />
<%if (owner != "test") 
          { //do stuff 
 } %>
</form>
</body>
```

Content Page

```
<body runat="server">
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
<%if (owner != "test") 
          { //do stuff } %>
</form>
</body>
```

My problem is that the Master Page doesn't recognize the variable (owner). It doesn't find it in the current context. Whereas the Content Page finds it in the current context. What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only access class members by class instance so your code should be

**for content page:**
Define an interface with a property, implement that interface in your master page and access interface property by typecasting master page property into interface on content page.
See the below example.

```
<body runat="server">
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
<uc3:IDowner id="IDuser1" runat="server" />
<%if (IDuser1.owner != "test") 
          { //do stuff 
 } %>
</form>
</body>

public interface IMyMaster
{
string owner { get; }
}

public class YourMasterPage : MasterPage, IMyMaster
{
//enter code here
    public string owner
    {
        get
        {
            this.IDuser1.owner;
        }
    }
}
```

On ASPX

```
var oIMyInterface=this.MasterPage as IMyInterface;
if(oIMyInterface!=null && oIMyInterface.owner!="test")
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the Master Page finds the variable of the user control BUT NOT the content page. Since the user control is declared on the Master Page, how can I send its variable to the content page?